# how to make text value to number from the span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the text value to the number so I can put some calculations in the script.

```
<p>
     <span class="shopdetailInfoName">CONSUMER</span>
     <span class="shopdetailInfoCont">
         <strike><!--/number/price_consumer/-->
             <span class="won">$</span>
         </strike>
     </span>
</p>
```

so as you can see the price value coming from this `<!--/number/price_consummer/-->` which website developer make it is work.

I try to make some script like this ->

```
var a = document.getElementById ('shopdetailInfoCont');
```

to bring the price value as a number but `.shopdetailInfoCont` include `","` and `"$"`
so it bring that value to text not the number.

How can I bring the value as the number?

as a result, I want to make like this

```
(ex ) - product price : 45.50 $ )
```

if you apply `-20$` discount, price will be `25.50$`

any help will be so appreciated thanks!

Comment: Various ways to convert the value to number, simplest is `* 1`

Comment: Can you change the html?  There are better ways than parsing text to get rid of unwanted characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = document.getElementById ('shopdetailInfoCont');    
floated_amount = parseFloat(a.replace(/[^0-9.-]/g, ''));
```

just try this regex to remove strings from your element value.

Thanks.

Comment: thkanks a lot! it is exactly what i want! :) thanks again and hava a nice day! :D

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the below shouldn't work cause your class is named `shopdetailInfoCont` not its id.

```html
var a = document.getElementById ('shopdetailInfoCont');
```

Second, I don't think there is a way to get a value like you wanted, but you what you can do is get 45.50 $ and with javascript `parseFloat()` function will return 45.50 from that text.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong function to retrieve your element. You have the class set but not an id.

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName() to get your element. This returns an array, so you'll access your element with the 0 index.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("won")[0].innerHTML = "Product Price: $" + price
```